# Searching path as search pattern in grep command

Tags: shell, quoting, variable-substitution

I have saved the path in the variable .

```
var="/home/myfolder/subfolder"
```

Need to search whether the path in available in a text file using grep.

```
grep -l '${var}' * >abc.txt
```

I'm trying to list the file names which has the above path but it's not working. How to search for path in a file using grep?

Comment: Using double quote instead of single quote `grep -Fl "${var}"`. `-F` for fixed string instead of regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables are not expanded to values when they are put within single quotes, they are treated literally then.

You need to use double quotes :

```
grep -l -- "${var}" *
```